# redirect and white page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following js code:

```
$.get('/desk/AddTicketToCart', { clientId: clientId}, function(data) {           
});
```

And controller's action:

```
public ActionResult AddTicketToCart(int clientId)
{
   // do work
   return new RedirectResult("/", true);    
}
```

But, I get white page and url not changed in address bar. I also tryed the following:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
```

but, I also get white page.
How to make redirect properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect in server won't help you here since you're making a ajax call. You need to set the new url in js in the callback.

```
$.get('/desk/AddTicketToCart', { clientId: clientId}, function(data) { 
   window.location = // the url          
});
```